# Find the domain of $\sec^{-1}(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Find the domain of $\sec^{-1}(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$

---

Since the domain of definition of $\sec^{-1} x$ is $x\leq-1$ or $x\geq 1$.
So $(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}\leq -1$ or $(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}\geq 1$
The domain of $(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is known to be $[-2,0)\cup(0,1)$.
I am stuck here.Please help.

Comment: The negative part of the domain of $\sec^{-1}$ is irrelevant. Everything will be OK between $x=0$ and $x=1$. Between $-2$ and $0$ is different, I think it will turn out $(-1/2,0)$ is not in the  domain.

Comment: How does $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ come in the domain.I have not understood.@AndréNicolas

Comment: I wrote  it is not in the domain. This is because on that interval $(2+x)/(1-x)$ is $\gt 1$, so when you raise that to the negative power $1/x$ you get a number $\lt 1$, so a number not in the domain of the inverse secant. The part $(-2,-1/2]$, however, is in the domain, and, as I mentioned, so is $(0,1)$.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia Can you prove that The domain of $(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is $[-2,0)\cup(0,1)$.<br>

Comment: @AndréNicolasDec i have posted the correct answer you should see

Answer (score 0):

$\Longrightarrow$The Range of $(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$ =
[0,$\infty$)

The domain of Sec$^{-1}x$ = $\mathbb{R}$- (-1,1)

$\Longrightarrow$1$\leq$$\left(\frac{2+x}{1-x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$\Longrightarrow$
x$\geq$ -$\frac{1}{2}$$\Longrightarrow$ the domain of $\sec^{-1}(\frac{2+x}{1-x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$
is [$\frac{-1}{2}$,1) -$\left\{ 0\right\} $